# Не могу выгрузить FastReport отчет на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, fastreport

Столкнулся с проблемой, что на домене выгрузка отчета не работает и выбрасывает ошибку

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

выгрузка происходит следующим образом:

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable("Table");

        String Sklad = ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text;
        String Stack = ddlStack.SelectedItem.Text;
        String Pocket = ddlPocket.SelectedItem.Text;
        String tagText = ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text + "." + ddlStack.SelectedItem.Text + "." + ddlPocket.SelectedItem.Text;

        table.Columns.Add("ZONE_NAME");
        table.Columns.Add("STACK_NAME");
        table.Columns.Add("COUNT_OF_POCKETS");
        table.Columns.Add("BARCODE");
        TableRow rownew = new TableRow();
        table.Rows.Add(rownew);

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            row["zone_name"] = Sklad;
            row["stack_name"] = Stack;
            row["count_of_pockets"] = Pocket;
            row["BARCODE"] = tagText;
        }
        //формирование отчета FastReport
        string ReportName = "Barcode.frx";
        string pp = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ReportTemplates/FastReport/" + ReportName);

        WebReport WebRep = new WebReport();
        FastReport.Utils.Config.WebMode = true;
        WebRep.Report = new FastReport.Report();
        WebRep.Report.Load(pp);
        WebRep.Report.RegisterData(table, "Table");

        WebRep.Report.Prepare();
        FastReportExports.ToPdf(WebRep.Report);
        WebRep.Report.Dispose();
        WebRep.Dispose();
```

Когда дебаггер доходит до строки : `WebRep.Report.Load(pp);`

то выбрасывает алерт типо

> Can't find object oracle data connection

но локально на работу это не влияет, и локально я могу запустить PDF-файл.

Что ему нужно? пробовал добавлять коннект к БД, но толку с этого ноль. Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: `Can't find object oracle data connection` намекает что в отчете есть соединение с oracle. Это так? и зачем оно вам нужно, если вы передаёте данные через `.RegisterData()`?

Comment: Все верно, я решил свою проблему создав сначала шаблонную xml и xsd, после исправил подключение для моего FastReport. и все заработало, прошу используйте ваш комментарий как ответ!